# Computer won't boot after uninstalling Ubuntu and reinstalling windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, mbr

Hello fellow Internet users,

So I decided to install Ubuntu, formatting my hard drive to do so, after a few months I decided to go back to Windows, so I formatted my hard drive and reinstalled Windows using a USB drive with a Windows iso burned on it, it installed perfectly fine, but now the computer won't boot.

It turns on, lights all work, fan starts, but the screen shows the manufacturer's logo, then restarts 3-5 seconds later.

I can't use any of the F keys, such as accessing BIOS or booting directly from a USB or CD (f9).Qs

I've tried boot-repair-disk, a Ubuntu live disk, Windows recovery disk.... And I still can't get past the manufacturer's logo.

Any advice on how to proceed?

My system is a Samsung Series 7 Chronos

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with your GPT/MBR. If you cannot access the BIOS, **unplug your PC and put the battery away (since it's a laptop)**, open it up and find a battery on the motherboard that looks like this one:

[image: CMOS Battery]

And then wait a few seconds. Then put it back in the boot the PC. It will restart the BIOS configuration and then you should be able to use repair disks, et cetera.

**P.S.** Before opening the PC, touch something metallic that connects to the ground (i.e. a metal sink) in order to discharge any static electricity you may carry. This will protect you PC when you open it up because some circuits are vulnerable to static electricity.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can't figure out how to add a picture to the comment (I'm using my phone), but I opened the back and there is a small plastic circular thing connected to the motherboard, stuck on with glue, and I removed the connector for that, and the BIOS didn't restart. Now there's another circular piece that looks like it could be the battery, but it would require taking off almost every part to get to it. Would the BIOS battery be that covered with stuff? Should I give it a try? Or is the plastic thing the battery?

Comment: The battery is almost always a button cell about 20mm in diameter and usually in some type of button cell holder that is soldered in.  There could be some kind of insulating cover over it.  The only thing I can think of that would be round, plastic, and glued on, with a wire and connector would be a little speaker.  The CMOS battery typically lasts on the order of 4-5 years and you don't often need to remove it for a purpose like this, so they don't design the laptop with battery serviceability  as a goal.

Answer (score 0):

**My story**

Hello, I suffered same situation two days ago, computer won't boot can't get past the manufacturer's logo. After searching internet helplessly, I discovered that problem was with my **RAM**, the **carbon build up** on ram stopped computer from booting, After cleaning the RAM from Acetone. Voila it started again.

**What to do**-

My conclusion is that clean your ram and then try booting the PC. Here's the guide to clean the ram- "[how to clean your ram](http://geekytips.com/blog/cleaning-the-ram)", If that is not the problem it might be the **CMOS battery** that is creating problem, you need to change it here's a guide- "[Replacing the battery](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/625-replacing-the-battery-of-your-motherboard-cmos-battery)".

**Reference**

Personally experienced.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I don't know RAM on a motherboard could get dirty (I'm new to the whole physic side of computing), but I'll give it a try!

Comment: @barlowmen Also check the **CMOS** battery, there's guide in my answer. or here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ao866I9XpTo)

Comment: I would worry about using acetone.  If you need a solvent, 91% or higher isopropyl alcohol (available at drug stores and supermarkets) would avoid the risk of damaging the plastic or coatings.  Use it on a cotton swab and clean only the contact areas.